# java - how to make request scoped configuration in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

i wanna make request scoped configuration for Jackson serializer based on request parameter, so my problem is the configuration runs in a different thread and only runs when the app stars, how i can make java reconfigure Jackson serializer in every request ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have request scoped config. Instead make the Jackson serializer bean request scoped and return instance with necessary config.

You can use approach described here
[instanciation of a request scoped bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486763/instanciation-of-a-request-scoped-bean)

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeansConfig {
  @Bean
  @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  public RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean() {
     //if needed set the required parameters
     return new RequestScopedBean();
  }         
}
```

Just return here your serializer instance. Then just autowire it wehre it's necessary

Comment: thanks @StanislavL for your quick reply, the probem that i'm facing is autowiring HttpServerRequest in my configuration and its always null , so the question is how i can autowire request in my BeanSerializerModifier ?